# How do I set fixed distance between characters using TextKit

Tags: objective-c, textkit

I use `TextKit` to draw a long text. Paragraph alignment is `NSTextAlignmentJustified`, `hyphenationFactor` is on.

Usually it works great, but sometimes I see the line like this: `"L o n g t e x t"`. Is there a way to draw such lines as `"Long____text"`? I.e. set constant distance between characters with flexible spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your own character layout, you'll need to subclass the layout manager (NSLayoutManager).